# Finish multiple activities without animation

Tags: android, android-activity

In my Android application, I have a fairly linear process of about 5 Activities. With the current implementation, I simply build up a stack of the activities. In other words, the flow is something like the following:

Home -> Screen 1 -> Screen 2 -> Screen 3 -> Screen 4 -> Screen 5

After Screen 5, I want to go back to Screen 1. I currently do this by using `Activity.setResult`, and checking for the result in `onActivityResult`. If the result is set, I immediately finish the Activity.

This works fine, unless I enable the "Don't keep activities" developer option on my phone (on ICS). In that case, the user can briefly see each activity popping up before it is finished again.

Is there a way to avoid all the Activities popping up when removing them from the stack? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing? Should I just ignore this behavior, and assume users won't ever see this on real devices?

Note that I can't use something like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and launch Screen 1 directly from Screen 5, since Screen 5 does not know at which Activity it should stop (for reasons I won't go into in this post).